# Prove $ \int_{-x}^{x} \frac{t^2 e^t}{e^t + 1} \, dt = \frac{x^3}{3}$ for every real $x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Just like in the title, one of the problems given in our homework is to prove that for every real $x$ the following equality is true: $$ \int_{-x}^{x} \frac{t^2 e^t}{e^t + 1} \, dt = \frac{x^3}{3}$$

I've been facing this for 2 days straight now, and am absolutely dumbstruck on how to do this. We aren't allowed to calculate the antiderivative of this problem.

The only hint we were given is to think of an operation that will cancel out the integral on the left side of the equality. But even after rereading out learning material again and again, I simply couldn't find anything helpful.

However, I would much rather getting a hint rather than the solution if possible.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:
Even after reading the solution written below, I still feel like something's not clicking in my head. If possible, a detailed explanation would be ideal (and thanks in advance for going through the trouble for me).

Comment: Hint:   $e^t = e^t + 1 - 1$

Comment: Hint: perform that change of integration variables from $t$ to $s$ via $t=-s$. The value of the integral does not change. Take the average of the original form and the one after the change of variables.

Comment: FYI, after using Presage's hint, i.e., $e^t=e^t+1-1$, with the resulting $\int_{-x}^x\frac{t^2}{e^t+1}dt$, an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B-x%7D%5E%7Bx%7D%5Cfrac%7Bt%5E2e%5Et%7D%7Be%5Et%2B1%7Ddt%3D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E3%7D%7B3%7D%24&p=1) shows either the specific [Evaluating the integral $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{x^2\,dx}{e^x+1}$](/q/919825), or the more general [calculate $\int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)}{1+e^x}dx$](/q/3049683), to get the result. Note that I also confirmed that Gary's hint works quite well too.

Comment: Leibniz Rule...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint 1: Fundamental theorem of calculus

Hint 2: Let $F(x)=\displaystyle\int^x_{-x}\dfrac{t^2e^t}{e^t+1}~dt$. What is $F(0)$?.

**Edit.** Let's me provide the exact solution below in case you need.

> Hint 1: We apply fundamental theorem of calculus on $F$. That is, $$F'(x)=\dfrac{x^2e^x}{e^x+1}\dfrac{dx}{dx}-\dfrac{(-x)^2e^{-x}}{e^{-x}+1}\dfrac{d(-x)}{dx}=x^2\left(\dfrac{e^x}{e+1}+\dfrac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}+1}\times\dfrac{e^x}{e^x}\right)=x^2$$Hence, $F(x)=\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\text{constant}$. By Hint 2, $F(0)=0$, so you have shown that $F(x)=\dfrac{x^3}{3}$.

Comment: It occurs to me that I'm dumb and still don't have any clue on what to do... $F(0)=0$ because it is a single point, but what do I infer from this?

Comment: Hint 1 provides you the antiderivative of $F$, so $F(x)=\dfrac{x^3}{3}+C$ but how do you know which $C$ is? You need some specific value of $F(x)$.

Comment: @EmanuelL Compute $F'(x)$ via hint 1.

Comment: I understand that what I am searching for is: $F(x)-F(-x)$. How were you able to conclude that $(x^3)/3 + C$ is the antiderivative?

Comment: You are not searching for $F(x)-F(-x)$. $F(x)$ is exactly the integral you want. Your goal is to show $F(x)=\dfrac{x^3}{3}$ under my definition.

Comment: It is wrong to provide  a complete solution to a homework problem. OP even said a complete solution is not sought after.

Comment: Even after reading the solution, I honestly don't get it... I feel stupid or that I am missing fundamental knowledge or understanding...

Comment: @geetba290krm That's why I give a spoiler alert over the solution, you can choose to not see this, but in case you need, there is extra guidance to them. I don't think giving soln to OP is harming him.

Comment: Hopefully I'm not mistaken, but I think its the definition of $F(x)$ that confuses me, and how you got it's derivative.

Comment: I have a last silly question. You say that if we take the derivative of $F(x)=G(x)-G(-x)$ we get $F'(x)=G'(x)-G'(-x)(-1)$. Does the $-1$ come from the chain rule?

Comment: @EmanuelL Yes, it comes from the chain rule. You may also take a look at [the Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).